# spring @controller vs @RestController error whitelabel error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I created a basic Spring MVC project in STS IDE.
When I try to add a controller I add the annotation @Controller and run the spring boot program, I get the following error:-(Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.), but when I add a @RestController the method returns the 'hello' string. Please help me out on how to fix it using @Controller and please let me know why this happened.

**Sample code:**

```
package com.adithya.spring.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String Hello() {
    return "Hello";

}
}
```

Also, my **pom.xml** file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.adithya</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyApplication</name>
<description>Login &amp; Reg</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[Project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9REE.png) .

Comment: change request mapping like this `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/")`

Comment: Your Pages are JSP or HTML ?? Have you added View Resolver for same ...

Comment: Please add your spring configuration file in question.

Comment: @Sangam I do not have a spring configuration file as I am using spring boot.

Comment: @Ashish My pages are .jsp and Deadpool I changed the requestmapping but it didnt work